# Convert fraction text into percentages without macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have the following spreadsheet with marks typed into as text. What is the quickest way to convert them all to percentages?

If the marks were typed with = in front then it would be easy as I can change the format, but they are not. I have a macro approach but it is very tedious since I have to enter it in every spreadsheet I use. Are there any quicker ways?

Comment: Try =LET(range,A1:A2,pos,FIND("/",range),LEFT(range,pos-1)/RIGHT(range,LEN(range)-pos)*100)

Comment: Or, Try `=LET(r,A2:A10,(TEXTBEFORE(r,"/")/TEXTAFTER(r,"/")))` and format as percentage.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Doesn't work on Windows version. Keeps giving error

Comment: Hi @Bob that error means your regional settings uses semicolons instead of commas, can you replace those commas with semicolons and can try. `=LET(r;A2:A10;(TEXTBEFORE(r;"/")/TEXTAFTER(r;"/")))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Nope, same problem

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Comma is fine, but it doesn't recognise r

Comment: ok, can you share the excel link in comments? or can you change all the `r` to `a`? may be small r is reserved

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Now it gives #name? error.

Comment: Alright share me the excel link here. `#Name?` error is because the function is not supported in your version of excel

Comment: It says the transfer requested has been deleted. Also mention your excel version. share proper onedrive excel link

Comment: Are you using MS365?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Yes, problem is it works on my mac version but I need it to work on windows version (office 2019)

Comment: ok, need to change the formula then one moment. here you can see [Working on my end](https://imgur.com/gallery/XQxYKDd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the combination of <kbd>LEFT()</kbd> & <kbd>RIGHT()</kbd> Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E4`

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(B4,FIND("/",B4)-1)/RIGHT(B4,LEN(B4)-FIND("/",B4)),0)
```

---

Ofcourse you need to fill down and fill right.

---

Alternative approach, which I have commented above works with **MS365**

Using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE()</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTAFTER()</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E4`

```
=LET(r,B4:B33,IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(r,"/")/TEXTAFTER(r,"/"),0))
```

---